# OpenCV and reading image with floating point data

Tags: opencv

I use OpenCV to read the image. Then I use Matlab to load the same image.
Then I display the images. For OpenCV loaded image, the image is has no picture inside and just gray plane. For Matlab loaded image, it has the image what I want.
The image pixel values are very small floating point data like 0.0021. The code I used to load the image is shown as follow.

```
`Mat image(IMAGE_ROW, IMAGE_COL, CV_64FC3);
Mat  gray(IMAGE_ROW, IMAGE_COL, CV_64FC1);
image = imread(filespath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );// Read the file
cv::imshow("Image", image);
cvtColor( image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY, 1);
cv::imshow("gray", gray);`
```

Why I can't have the same image as loaded by Matlab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well you can't do it with imwrite()/imread()  as stated before.

but you can save/load floating point Mats using the FileStorage, like this:

```
Mat fm = Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32FC3); // dummy data

FileStorage fs("my.yml", FileStorage::WRITE );
fs << "mat1" << fm;  //choose any key here, just be consistant with the one below
```

and read back in:

```
Mat fm;
FileStorage fs("my.yml", FileStorage::READ );
fs["mat1"] >> fm;
```

Comment: I need to load myimage.jpg as all my images are captured in jpg format. Then the image pixel values are very small floating point like 0.00123, 0.00245, etc. What is the best way to load those images directly from the jpg files. As you suggested, we can load the jpg in Matlab then save as yml. Then load again in OpenCV. But is there sth I can tweak so that I can load directly from OpenCV for such an image?

Comment: oh, wait , above is all opencv code, not matlab. and you just can't store a floating point image in a jpg, or png. it's not a limitation of opencv, but of the file format

Comment: yes I know the above code is for opencv. i see. How can I pass you my jpg file? If you have time, can you pls test loading from opencv. When I read that jpg file in Matlab, I received an image buffer with small pixel values. Then in OpenCv, just receive a gray image.

Comment: unfortunately no matlab here.  well, octave..  ok. just load it to imgur or such.  and i still have my doubts, that you can save a jpg with floats from matlab correctly

Comment: can send email? that is more straightforward. What is the number?

Comment: you say: "all my images are captured in jpg format." how is that done ? where do they come from ? when you load them in matlab, how do you know the pixel format ? are you just assuming they are float, and treating them like furtheron ? that might be the error in the first place .

Comment: don't like my email on a website viewed by thousands of people, so http://imgur.com/ or simily, pleas ;)

Comment: Mat img = imread("t28rA1y.jpg"); 
    cerr << img.rows << " " << img.cols << " " << img.channels() << " " << img.type() << endl;
480 640 3 16    ( that's CV_8UC3, no floats!) again, rethink your matlab code ?

Comment: but you receive small integer values right. if you imshow, do you see the original image?

Comment: small integer values yes. (lots of black pixels).  yes, i can see the image ok (imshow(); waitKey(0); ) //don't forget the waitkey() !

Comment: I create the img as img = cv::Mat(480,640,CV_64FC3), then i read.so I receive gray image

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly initialize a `cv::Mat` image before calling `cv::imread`, it will initialize the image properly according to the size and format of the image read. So it doesn't matter that you've initialized your image with `(IMAGE_ROW, IMAGE_COL, CV_64FC3)`.

OpenCV has no capabilities for writing/reading floating point images. From [cv::imwrite](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite) manual:

> Only 8-bit (or 16-bit in the case of PNG, JPEG 2000 and TIFF)
>   single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be
>   saved using this function.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to load image with floating point data in OpneCV?

Comment: Yes. Because there is no wide-spread image format capable of storing floating point values. Except HDR.

Comment: @Mikhail Except `tiff` or `jpeg`. Libtiff can actually do it and these kinds of images are often used in remote sensing and also for videogame textures. Programs like ImageJ and Matlab can open them. At the end of the day this an omission by the OpenCV people.

Comment: This is not true, you can load float images with opencv `Mat img= imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);`

Comment: @mrgloom The quote is about `cv::imwrite`. Concerning `imread`, I suppose that it can load it as a binary data, but it cannot automatically deduce proper floating point type.

Answer (score 2):

You can load float images with opencv `Mat img= imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);`

Answer (score 0):

Tried @berak solution, but got a "Missing , between elements" exception. As stated in [this](http://code.opencv.org/issues/969) bug report, you must release the FileStorage object after writing operation, otherwise it will not properly finalise the file writing and thus raising that exception. Then, the corrected version of the codelet should be:

```
Mat fm = Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32FC3); // dummy data
FileStorage fs("my.yml", FileStorage::WRITE );
fs << "mat1" << fm;  //choose any key here, just be consistant with the one below
fs.release(); //Release the file and finish the writing.
```